# Javascript Class instead of ID for hide/show function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen a few questions like this but honestly, I'm a SUPER noob with JS and have no idea what I'm doing :S So I thought I'd put the coding I do have and see if someone can help.

Basically what I have is the JS to show and then hide a div with an ID name, but I want it for Class names instead as I have multiple classes that I want to show or hide with a click of a button. I'm making a page kinda with a sorting system for my friend. It's for a Masterlist of Trans* characters RPed on Tumblr and I'd like it so that you can show JUST MtF trans characters and hide all other categories of characters or hide JUST MtF characters and show all other categories of characters, for example (as that is legit one of the buttons I want to have).

This is the JS I have, does anyone know how to edit this to make it work for classes? Thanks!

```
<script>

    function myFunction1() {

      var x = document.getElementById('all');

    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
      document.getElementById("mtf").style.display = "block"; 
      document.getElementById("ftm").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("nonbinary").style.display = "block
      document.getElementById("fluidqueer").style.display = "block";

    }
    </script>
    <script>

    function myFunction2() {

      var x = document.getElementById('mtf');

    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
      document.getElementById("ftm").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("nonbinary").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("fluidqueer").style.display = "none";

    }
    </script>
    <script>

    function myFunction3() {

      var x = document.getElementById('ftm');

    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
      document.getElementById("mtf").style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById("nonbinary").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("fluidqueer").style.display = "none";

    }
    </script>
    <script>

    function myFunction4() {

      var x = document.getElementById('nonbinary');

    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
      document.getElementById("mtf").style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById("ftm").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("fluidqueer").style.display = "none";

    }
    </script>
    <script>

    function myFunction5() {

      var x = document.getElementById('fluidqueer');

    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
      document.getElementById("mtf").style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById("ftm").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("nonbinary").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("fluidqueer").style.display = "none";

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I went through the code over and over  and still have no idea what you are hoping to do with it.

Comment: Okay, so basically what I'm looking for is, when you, for example, click on the MtF button, I want all divs with the class name .mtf to be the ONLY divs showing and every other div (.ftm, .nonbinary, .fluidqueer) to hide. Then if you click that same button again, I want ONLY the .mtf divs to hide and every other div to show.

Comment: I guess jQuery is allowed. Right?

Comment: [For something slightly different, try this](https://jsfiddle.net/v4aqbrfg/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps,

```js
$(".filter-btn").click(function() {
  var className = $(this).attr('data-target');
  if ($("div").not("." + className).is(":visible")) {
    $("." + className).show();
    $("div").not("." + className).hide();
  } else {
    $("." + className).hide();
    $("div").not("." + className).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mtf">MTF</div>
<div class="mtf">MTF</div>
<div class="mtf">MTF</div>
<div class="mtf">MTF</div>

<div class="ftm">FTM</div>
<div class="ftm">FTM</div>
<div class="ftm">FTM</div>
<div class="ftm">FTM</div>

<div class="nonbinary">Non Binary</div>
<div class="nonbinary">Non Binary</div>
<div class="nonbinary">Non Binary</div>
<div class="nonbinary">Non Binary</div>
<div class="nonbinary">Non Binary</div>
<div class="fluidqueer">Fluid Queer</div>
<div class="fluidqueer">Fluid Queer</div>
<div class="fluidqueer">Fluid Queer</div>
<div class="fluidqueer">Fluid Queer</div>
<div class="fluidqueer">Fluid Queer</div>

<input class="filter-btn" type="button" value="MTF" data-target="mtf">
<input class="filter-btn" type="button" value="FTM" data-target="ftm">
<input class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Non Binary" data-target="nonbinary">
<input class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Fluiq Queer" data-target="fluidqueer">
```

In your case, common selector can be

var $all = $('.fandomboxes div');

So the code becomes

```
  $(".filter-btn").click(function() {
    var $all = $('.fandomboxes div'),
    className = $(this).attr('data-target');
    if ($all.not("." + className).is(":visible")) {
      $("." + className).show();
      $all.not("." + className).hide();
    } else {
      $("." + className).hide();
      $all.not("." + className).show();
    }
  });
```

Comment: That does what I want! :D But is is possible to have buttons to click instead of the text within each different type of div? I ask cause the text within each div is gonna be a link to various RP blogs on Tumblr.

Also, I'm assuming I'd replace "div" with "mtf" for the mtf button and so forth? Sorry complete noob! lol :P

Comment: Thank you! I'll put it in and test it out right now! :D

Comment: it's working!! Although not completely :( When I click the buttons it HIDES that class instead of showing JUST that div. And when I click a second time, nothing happens :/ Maybe I put it in wrong? I did this for each class.  <script>
    $(".filter-btn").click(function() {
  var className = $(this).attr('data-target');
  if ($("mtf").not("." + className).is(":visible")) {
    $("." + className).show();
    $("mtf").not("." + className).hide();
  } else {
    $("." + className).hide();
    $("mtf").not("." + className).show();
  }
});
</script>

Comment: In your if statement before not youll have to call a common selector, common for all the `div`s  you are toggling. So it becomes something like `if($('div.someCommonClass').not())` @AllyB

Comment: @AllyB I can help you more if you can post your HTML code.

Comment: This is the WHOLE page! Thanks again, btw!
https://pastebin.com/BGALsMGQ

Comment: @AllyB you dont have to write click functions for each class. Just one will do for all of them all you have to do is get a common selector for all the divs.

Comment: Oh okay! All the divs that the buttons will effect are within the div .fandomboxes which i used multiple times to make it all easier to edit :P I'll try that! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Dan! I just wanna make sure, is this correct then? Because nothing is happening :S
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".filter-btn").click(function() {
    var $all = $(".listarea table td div").not('.fandomboxes');
  if ($all.not("." + className).is(":visible")) {
    $("." + className).show();
    $("fandomboxes").not("." + className).hide();
  } else {
    $("." + className).hide();
    $("fandomboxes").not("." + className).show();
  }
});
</script>

Comment: @AllyB If thats not working try giving a class to all the `div`s that you are toggling like `<div class="ftm toggle-data"></div> <div class="mft toggle-data">` and then change `$all` to `$all = $('.toggle-data');`

Comment: If you don't mind Dan, I set up a jsfiddle, so hopefully, you can help there? Cause maybe my noob brain is just doing something wrong with the js lol :P Cause it's still not working ://
https://jsfiddle.net/n0qcu2ng/1/

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` is the function that finds classes.

However, because of the way classes are designed to work versus IDs (there can be multiple elements with a class versus only one with the ID), it returns an array of elements instead of one.

JavaScript's `style` function only works on single elements, so you'll need to iterate over them:

```
var elements = getElementsByClassName('<your class>');

elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.<your style> = <your property>
});
```

Comment: That's what I'm aiming for! :P I have the classes multiple times on the page, and want to hide/show them ALL onclick. I'll try it out now, thanks!

Comment: So I switched out every "getElementById" with "getElementsByClassName" but when I click on any of the buttons nothing is happening :S Would it make any difference if I posted the WHOLE page's coding? This is the only JS on it though, and the buttons look like this
"<button onclick="myFunction2()">MtF</button>"

Comment: So now it's returning an array. I figured JavaScript's `style` function may have had the intelligence to work on both single elements or arrays of elements but it only works on single elements. You'll have to iterate over them - I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help JackHasaKeyboard! I'll wait to see your updated answer.

Comment: No prob :] so that should do it, but for what your code is worth it would be best to just do it over (your code can be boiled down to a single, more intuitive function). You want me to just re-work it and justify it to you?

Comment: Ya sure!! If it can be simplified I'll take it! lol :P And I'm very grateful for your help!! I do have another question though, what do you mean by/what do I put for <your style> and <your property>? Sorry, I'm EXTREMELY nooby with JS, and I'm sure that's like some basic 101 stuff but I just don't know yet.

Comment: No prob :] everyone starts out programming like this, you make things work in the most literal sense that's kinda redundant and roundabout and then slowly work backwards understanding what all the things mean and what the most logical way to do it is. Gotta walk my dog but I'll be back in about an hour with revised code. EDIT: Oh yeah, those things are just there to show you what to replace with what you happen to want (Stack Overflow answers should be about the premise and not for the specific person at hand). Replace <your style> with `display` and so-fourth.